# Create Model for 4-D kind of array in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, backend

I have some *logic* constructed for my *Database* for a Django webapp but I am quite unable to convert it into *Model form* that can be used in `Models.py` :

```
User : U
Transaction-ID : T
Datetime : D
Transaction-ID Status-1 for a today : A[0]
Transaction-ID Status-2 for a today : A[1]
Transaction-ID Status-3 for a today : A[2]
```

For above a logic can be constructed with `N` *users* : `U[N]` where `U[i] -> T[i][]` *transaction*, and each *transaction* has 3 transactional attributes `T[j] -> A[j][3]`. How should I proceed with constructing a *model* for the given details. Also if possible how can I store *date wise Model* for the three `A[k]` statuses of *Transaction* and add them for a *week wise* and *month wise* average and proceed with making the db.

**Use Case :**

A particular ***user*** could have done ***variable number*** of ***Transactions***, and for each *transaction* there is a *key* provided used to get the *status* of that particular *transaction*. Like the ***power points*** earned, ***bonus points*** earned and ***fame points*** earned. For *periodically* updating the 3 *points* earned *daily*, *weekly* and *monthly* ***across all transactions*** done by ***that user*** and storing them in the Database ***for each and every user*** what should be done.

Since my project is based on *SQLite* that runs inbuilt with *Django framework* which I am unfamiliar with, I need to understand how *models* should be used and how to implement this use case.

Calling it 4 dimensional because ***entry** = **U**[**N**][**M**][3][**D**]*

Comment: have the objective intuition, instead of the list intuition.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Could you elaborate your comment please.

Comment: Does a code which contains three nested Django model that its data stored on an object instead of a 3D list help you?

Comment: Examples would be greatly appreciated, also I've managed to make a small model but the datetime part is not clearly working out in a modelform. @BenyaminJafari

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I see what you meant by object intuition clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put some part of my project for this purpose and apologize for not summarizing the code in this answer (because I think summarizing it maybe would have mistakes without test so I decided used copy-paste a tested code).

---

When I want to read four nested Django admin model (4D) and use them in the code, I did the following procedures:

## models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE

MODBUS_TYPES = (('tcp', 'Tcp'), ('udp', 'Udp'), ('ascii', 'Ascii'), ('rtu', 'Rtu'))


class BatteryMonitoringServer(models.Model):
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    server_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BatteryMonitoringDevice(models.Model):
    bm_id = models.ForeignKey(BatteryMonitoringServer, on_delete=CASCADE)
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=MODBUS_TYPES)
    bm_device_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='127.0.0.1', null=True)
    bm_device_port = models.IntegerField(default=5558, null=True)
    baud_rate = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=9600)

class BatteryMonitoringSubDevice(models.Model):
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    sub_bm_count = models.IntegerField(default=4, null=True, blank=True, name='bm')
    fk = models.ForeignKey(BatteryMonitoringDevice, on_delete=CASCADE)

class BatteryMonitoringMeta(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    module = models.ForeignKey(BatteryMonitoringSubDevice, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

---

## conf_reader.py

```
from battery_monitoring.models import BatteryMonitoringServer
from delta_device.utility import DictEncoder

class BMSubDeviceConf(object):
    def __init__(
            self,
            start,
            name,
            unit,
            bm,
            meta_data):

        self._start = start
        self._name = name
        self._unit = unit
        self._bm = bm
        self._meta_data = meta_data

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self._start

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def unit(self):
        return self._unit

    @property
    def bm(self):
        return self._bm

    @property
    def meta_data(self):
        return self._meta_data

class BMDeviceConf(object):
    def __init__(
            self,
            bm_id,
            start,
            name,
            method,
            bm_device_ip,
            bm_device_port,
            baud_rate,
            sub_devices=None):

        self._id = bm_id
        self._start = start
        self._name = name
        self._method = method
        self._bm_device_ip = bm_device_ip
        self._bm_device_port = bm_device_port
        self._baud_rate = baud_rate
        self._sub_devices = sub_devices or []

    def add_sub_device(self, sub_device):
        self._sub_devices.append(sub_device)

    def get_sub_devices(self):
        return self._sub_devices

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self._start

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def bm_device_ip(self):
        return self._bm_device_ip

    @property
    def bm_device_port(self):
        return self._bm_device_port

    @property
    def baud_rate(self):
        return self._baud_rate

class BMConf(object):
    def __init__(
            self,
            start,
            name,
            server_ip,
            devices=None,
    ):  # :( :| :) (: :p

        self._start = 'ON' if start else 'OFF'
        self._name = name
        self._server_ip = server_ip
        self._devices = devices or []

    def add_device(self, device):
        self._devices.append(device)

    def get_devices(self):
        return self._devices

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self._start

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def server_ip(self):
        return self._server_ip

def get_server():
    """Using list method to make a fast sql reading."""
    return list(BatteryMonitoringServer.objects.all())

def get_devices(dev):
    return list(dev.batterymonitoringdevice_set.all())

def get_sub_devices(sub_dev):
    return list(sub_dev.batterymonitoringsubdevice_set.all())

def get_metadata(metric):
    return list(metric.batterymonitoringmeta_set.all())

class BMReadConf(object):
    """BM configuration Reader"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get_bm_config(cls):
        """Read BM metrics and return it on a object list"""
        result = list()

        for srv in get_server():
            data = BMConf(srv.enable,
                          srv.name,
                          srv.server_ip,)

            for dev in get_devices(srv):
                device = BMDeviceConf(
                    dev.bm_id,
                    dev.enable,
                    dev.name,
                    dev.method,
                    dev.bm_device_ip,
                    dev.bm_device_port,
                    dev.baud_rate,
                )

                for sub_dev in get_sub_devices(dev):
                    meta_data = {}

                    for meta in get_metadata(sub_dev):
                        meta_data[meta.key] = meta.value

                    sub_device = BMSubDeviceConf(
                        sub_dev.enable,
                        sub_dev.name,
                        sub_dev.unit,
                        sub_dev.bm,
                        meta_data,
                        )

                    device.add_sub_device(sub_device)

                data.add_device(device)

            result.append(data)

        return result
```

---

## Usage (test.py)

```
from battery_monitoring.conf_reader import BMReadConf

conf_obj = BMReadConf()
configs = conf_obj.get_bm_config()

for cnf in configs:
    print(cnf.name)  # This is name field in BatteryMonitoringServer Table.
    devices = cnf.get_devices()
    
    for dev in devices:
        print(dev.baud_rate)  # This is baud_rate field in second nested table.
        sub_devices = dev.get_sub_devices()
    
        for sub_dev in sub_devices:
            print(sub_dev.unit)  # This is unit field in third nested table. 
            print(sub_dev.meta_data)  # This is meta_data table (fourth nested table).
```

---

I hope this would be useful.

---

[**NOTE**]:

Fourth nested table (*meta_data*) has a incremented key/value fields.